# Acer 3810T Black Screen of Death - Just a dead LCD backlight, way to fix?

Tags: lcd, acer-aspire, backlight, black-screen-of-death

I have an Acer Aspire 3810T and I recently encountered the black screen of death.  I've found articles suggesting that this could be a bug in the BIOS and that if I flash the BIOS it could fix it, but they all apply to the Acer Aspire One.  Does this hold true for the Aspire 3810T as well?  If not are there any possible fixes that don't involve monitor replacement or a new laptop?

Side note: the monitor *does* turn on, it's just the backlight that doesn't.  If you look very closely you can just make out the bright areas of the screen are there when the computer is on.  I've noticed in the past that the back light goes out when pressure is applied to certain areas of the monitor - which makes me worry that those areas got knocked hard enough to knock something out.

**Edit**:  I have now flashed the bios to the newest version, it did nothing for the dead screen.  I have confirmed that the computer and screen work fine - just the screen's backlight is out.  Is there anyway to get the backlight working again that doesn't involve replacing the whole screen?